# RDKit - Export pandas data frame with mol image

Tags: pandas, rdkit

I would like to know whether is it possible to export pandas dataframe with molecular image directly in excel file format?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In RDKit's PandasTools there is the funktion SaveXlsxFromFrame.

http://www.rdkit.org/Python_Docs/rdkit.Chem.PandasTools-module.html#SaveXlsxFromFrame

[XlsxWriter](https://pypi.org/project/XlsxWriter/) must be installed.

```
import pandas as pd
from rdkit import Chem
from rdkit.Chem import PandasTools

smiles = ['c1ccccc1', 'c1ccccc1O', 'c1cc(O)ccc1O']
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':['Benzene', 'Phenol', 'Hydroquinone'], 'SMILES':smiles})

df['Mol Image'] = [Chem.MolFromSmiles(s) for s in df['SMILES']]

PandasTools.SaveXlsxFromFrame(df, 'test.xlsx', molCol='Mol Image')
```