# Exported csv Data frame does not display pictures "chemical structures" rdkit

Tags: pandas, dataframe, export-to-csv, rdkit

I will appreciate any help on this.

When I tried to export my data frame" manipulated with pandas and rdkit all Chem" the df contains chemical structure images.

When exported as .Xls or Csv, it does not display the images. It only represents the images as links. I am confused about this.

What line of code can I use to rectify these?

these are my codes:

```
!pip install rdkit-pypi

from rdkit import Chem
from rdkit.Chem import Draw
from rdkit.Chem.Draw import IPythonConsole
from rdkit.Chem import Descriptors
from rdkit.Chem import AllChem
from rdkit.Chem import PandasTools
from rdkit import DataStructs
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/Smiles Only 890.csv')

PandasTools.AddMoleculeColumnToFrame(df,'Smiles','Molecules')
df.head()


#df.to_csv('Smiles_MolStructure.csv', index=False)


!pip install xlsxwriter


writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Smiles_MolStructure.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']
writer.save()
```

Comment: Use PandasTools for the export. Look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51366790/3748445

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RDKit - Export pandas data frame with mol image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51356324/rdkit-export-pandas-data-frame-with-mol-image)